# Get the int values from a .wav file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, signal-processing, wav, bytebuffer

I seem to have reached a dead-end. I try to display the first int values of a 32 bits per sample, 2 channels .wav file with the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inFile = new File("C:/.../1.wav");
    FileInputStream fstream = null;

    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fstream);
    byte[] bytes = null;

    try {
        bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    int num = wrapped.getInt();
    System.out.println(num);

}
```

But i'm not sure what the number displayed means. I get "1380533830", first of all if I understood correctly is the int value is the not from 0 to 2^32-1 but from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1.

If that's the case it should be the first int from the first channel, but when I do an *audioread* in matlab I get a completely different value : "-1376256". I tried to see if "1380533830" was a value somewhere in my *audioread* but it wasn't so I don't know what I did.

Comment: You may want to learn a hex editor so you can see exactly what is in your WAV file.  Check the specifications to understand the WAV format- there is most likely a header before the actual data come.

Comment: Oh is that what this is, I guess the question was very stupid then ...

Comment: I am not familiar with the WAV-format, but a header is very likely.   Your code will need to understand the data enough to detect the header and derive the location and actual format of the sound data.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean I guess this was the problem, I will look up the wave files specifications. Thank you